# Convert dynamically shaped query results into IEnumerabale or IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic

I am attempting to take the results of a Stored Procedure that that contains dynamic columns, different shapes of data, and convert that into an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.

In the middleware, I am using EF and since I have never worked with dynamic queries, I am at a loss. I looked at the `DataTable.ToSchemaTable()` to see if that could convert to anything useful and hit a wall. Recently, I started looking into dynamics, however, I still can't seem to figure out how to convert to `IEnumerable`.

The clientside needs to have data in the form of {"FieldName":"FieldValue"}, and the result set needs to be pre-processed via an `IEnumerable` prior to being converted to JSON.

Comment: Does the API expose a way to get the `DbDataReader`? Also, what inner type are you expect, an `IEnumerable<foo>`?

Comment: @Evan Trimboli - Ideally, I would like to do something like var list = DataTableConverter<anything>().Convert(dataTable); I have the code that converts the datatable to a known type, foo, however, I do not know the shape of the data returned from the SP. I might have to craft the JSON myself and bypass the third party server side grid components :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I am working with that solved the issue.

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> AsDynamicEnumerable(this DataTable table)
    {
        if (table == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dRow = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                var value = row[column.ColumnName];
                dRow[column.ColumnName] = Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? null : value;
            }

            yield return dRow;
        }
    }
}
```